# Which function do I have to call to crossfade the pane

Tags: android, cross-fade

i have a problem with the @mikepenz crossfader.

I like to open the crossfader additionally with an onClick method.

In XML layout I use the GmailStyleCrossFadeSlidingPaneLayout. This works perfect with swiping but I don't know how to do it by onClick.

so thanks for your help :)
http://mikepenz.github.io/Crossfader/

Answer (score 1):

From the page you linked

```
//check if the view is crossFaded
if (crossFader.isCrossFaded()) {
    //crossFade the view
    crossFader.crossFade();
}
```